The problem of mapping in creating a Generic Method
This Is My Models :
  public class Result1 
  { 
      public string Price { get; set; }
      public string Id { get; set; } 
  }
  public class Result2
  { 
      public string firstName { get; set; } 
      public string lastName { get; set; }
      public string Id { get; set; } 
  }
  public class JsonResult1
  { 
      public List<Product> ProductLists { get; set; } 
  }
  public class JsonResult2 
  {
      public List<User> UserLists { get; set; } 
  }

And This is My First And Second Methods
   public async Task<List<Result1>> GetFirstMethod(string id, string a)
   {
       var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult1>(a);

       var mylist = new List<Result1>();
       foreach (var item in info.ProductLists)
       {
           mylist.Add(new Result1()
           {
               Price = item.Price,
               Id = item.ID
           });
       }
       return mylist;
   }
   public async Task<List<Result2>> GetSecondMethod(string id, string a)
   {
       var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult2>(a);

       var mylist = new List<Result2>();
       foreach (var item in info.UserLists)
       {
           mylist.Add(new Result2()
           {
               firstName = item.FirstName,
               lastName = item.LastName,
               Id = item.ID
           });
       }
       return mylist;
   }
//And the third method and the fourth method and...


Each method has different models...
How to make a generic method for All the above methods??
The main problem is in the mapping part inside the list...
Is it even possible to do something like this?

"The main problem is in the mapping part inside the list" are you ok with modifying the parameter list of your method to pass in a Func<> to perform that mapping?

I'm not sure what benefit you're going to get by making a single generic method. You need to define how to do the mapping (selecting the "List" property from the info varaible, and mapping each list entry from the source to the output list) somewhere. It can be in their own methods, or the caller needs to do it. You can always pull the JSON parsing out and the caller can pass in the parsed object instead.

@gunr2171 I agree with any solution that solves the problem. Only I can't change classes "Result"s and "JsonResult"s.

Well, a User and a Product are completeöy different things, which have absolutely nothing in common. In other words: there's nothing generic in your models.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain Exactly.

Only I can't change classes "Result"s and "JsonResult"s then nothing can be done afaik

@gunr2171 The benefit is that I will have a generic method! Currently, I have about 10 methods, all of which are the same as above... Can I get help from the AutoMapper Or Mapster?

@IvanPetrov So it is not possible in your opinion?

@YaYA imo no, but following if somebody comes up with an original and maintainable solution given these constraints

So if the method is going to be generic, where will the mapping information be stored? How will you know what property to enumerate, and how to convert each list element? The way I see it, you've either got 10 methods with their own logic for how to convert their own special type of data, or each place you call the single generic method you need to specify that conversion logic.

@gunr2171 What do you think about ipodtouch0218's answer?

This is the most probably convoluted answer imaginable, but you can use a dictionary to keep delegates to map between the three different types:
public class Mapping {
    public static readonly Dictionary<(Type,Type), Mapping> RegisteredMappings = new();
    public Func<object,IEnumerable<object>> enumerate;
    public Func<object,object> map;
    
    public static void Register<T,M,R>(Func<T, IEnumerable<M>> enumerateFunc, Func<M, R> mappingFunc) where T : class where M : class where R : class {
        RegisteredMappings.Add((typeof(T), typeof(R)), new Mapping {
            enumerate = (object input) => enumerateFunc((T) input),
            map = (object input) => mappingFunc((M) input),
        });
    }
}

public static List<R> Get<T,R>(string id, string a) {
    if (!Mapping.RegisteredMappings.TryGetValue((typeof(T), typeof(R)), out Mapping mapping)) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"No mapping exists between {typeof(T).Name} and {typeof(R).Name}");
    }

    T info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(a);
    List<R> list = new();

    foreach (var item in mapping.enumerate(info)) {
        list.Add((R) mapping.map(item));
    }

    return list;
}

Example usage:
public static void Main()
{
    // Example JSON for JsonResult1 (Product) and JsonResult2 (User)
    string productJson = "{\"ProductLists\": [{\"Price\": \"100.00\", \"ID\": \"XYZ\"},{\"Price\": \"50.00\", \"ID\": \"ABC\"}]}";
    string userJson = "{\"UserLists\": [{\"FirstName\": \"Mark\", \"LastName\": \"B.\", \"ID\": \"XYZ\"},{\"FirstName\": \"Joseph\", \"LastName\": \"S.\", \"ID\": \"ABC\"}]}";

    // Register the mapping from JsonResult1 -> Result1 and JsonResult2 -> Result2 (using the Product/User classes as an intermediary)
    Mapping.Register<JsonResult1, Product, Result1>(EnumerateProducts, MapProduct);
    Mapping.Register<JsonResult2, User, Result2>(EnumerateUsers, MapUser);

    // Example usage
    List<Result1> productResults = Get<JsonResult1, Result1>("unused", productJson);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', productResults.Select(product => product.Price)));
    // -> 100.00,50.00

    List<Result2> userResults = Get<JsonResult2, Result2>("unused", userJson);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', userResults.Select(user => user.firstName)));
    // -> Mark,Joseph
}

public static IEnumerable<Product> EnumerateProducts(JsonResult1 jr1) => jr1.ProductLists;
public static Result1 MapProduct(Product p) {
    return new Result1 {
        Price = p.Price,
        Id = p.ID,
    };
}
public static IEnumerable<User> EnumerateUsers(JsonResult2 jr2) => jr2.UserLists;
public static Result2 MapUser(User u) {
    return new Result2 {
        firstName = u.FirstName,
        lastName = u.LastName,
        Id = u.ID
    };
}

This way you only need to register each mapping once on boot, and then you never have to reference them again. Simply calling the function with the input/result types specified will work.

Let me do a little test, it's really convoluted

It's convoluted because you can't modify your classes and there's no way to get access to the values in a generic / inherited way. This is probably the best you can do with your restrictions. (You only have to specify the Json->Class and Class->Result functions once)

Thank you, your answer has been confirm. All my code (all methods) was modified as what you wrote... only in one case I got problem... one of my methods has a JsonResult with 2 lists and I need both lists. ..but your code does not allow me to use more than 1 list
What should I do in this exceptioned?

Easiest way I'd say would be to combine the lists into one inside your enumerate function: IEnumerable<User> EnumerateUsers(JsonResult2 jr2) { List<User> results = new(); results.AddRange(jr2.UserGroupA); results.AddRange(jr2.UserGroupB); return results; } or if it's a 2d array you can use IEnumerable<User> EnumerateUsers(JsonResult2 jr2) => jr2.TwoDimensionalUsersArray.SelectMany(u => u);

UserGroupA and UserGroupB completeöy different things... results.AddRange(jr2.UserGroupA) Is Okey Next I have to do something like this: results.ForEach(y => y.Name = (UserGroupB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == y.ProductRef)).Name);

"UserGroupA and UserGroupB completely different things" the code in my answer only handles converting between TypeA -> MiddlemanType -> TypeB. If you have two different things then you'll need a completely different function (that wasn't stated as an example in the initial question)

Ok thanks - your code was great - it's an exception(1 of 10 methods) - can your code be modified with "Mapster"?

We can do the following (not pretty but we can't modify JsonResult*)
public async Task<List<TResult>> GetGenericMethod
<TResult, TJsonResult, TItem>(
string id, string a, Func<TItem, TResult> mapper
, Func<TJsonResult, IEnumerable<TItem>> getIterator)
 {
    TJsonResult info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TJsonResult>(a);
    // shorter version
    //return getIterator(info)
    //.Select(mapper)
    //.ToList();
    List<TResult> mylist = new List<TResult>();
    IEnumerable<TItem> enumerable = getIterator(info);
    foreach (var item in enumerable) {
        mylist.Add(mapper(item));
    }
    return mylist;
}

Example use:
var jsonResult1 = new JsonResult1();
jsonResult1.ProductLists = new List<Product>();
jsonResult1.ProductLists.Add(new Product { ID = "3", Price = "4" });
jsonResult1.ProductLists.Add(new Product { ID = "7", Price = "8" });

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult1);
Func<Product, Result1> mapper = p => new Result1 {
    Price = p.Price,
    Id = p.ID
}; // this can be a method and not a lambda

var result = await GetFirstMethod<Result1, JsonResult1, Product>(
"", serialized, mapper, r => r.ProductLists);
foreach (var element in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}

I've originally used a derived type from JSonResult1 that implemented IEnumerable<T> to get the enumerator to use, but inspired by another answer (from ipodtouch0218), there seems to be no real need for it and we can just have a Func<TJsonResult, IEnumerable<TItem>> for less verbose and just as functional code.

Thank you for your time. Let me do a little test

Use a single generic method with reflection to dynamically map JSON properties to model objects, avoiding multiple MapFromJson implementations. This centralizes and simplifies the mapping process across different types.
public interface IJsonResult
{
}


public class JsonResult1 : IJsonResult
{
    public List<Product> ProductLists { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResult2 : IJsonResult
{
    public List<User> UserLists { get; set; }
}

public class Result1
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Result2
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class DataService
{
    public async Task<List<T>> GetMethod<T, J>(string id, string jsonString) where J : IJsonResult
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => MapFromJson<T, J>(jsonString));
    }

    private List<T> MapFromJson<T, J>(string jsonString) where J : IJsonResult
    {
        var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<J>(jsonString);
        var mylist = new List<T>();

        // Use reflection to get the lists and map to the result type
        var listProperty = typeof(J).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType);
        if (listProperty != null)
        {
            var itemList = (IEnumerable<object>)listProperty.GetValue(info);

            foreach (var item in itemList)
            {
                var result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

                foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
                {
                    var itemProp = item.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (itemProp != null)
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(result, itemProp.GetValue(item));
                    }
                }

                mylist.Add(result);
            }
        }

        return mylist;
    }
}

// Usage
public async Task ExampleUsage()
{
    var dataService = new DataService();

    string jsonString1 = ""; // Your JSON string for Result1
    List<Result1> result1List = await dataService.GetMethod<Result1, JsonResult1>("someId", jsonString1);

    string jsonString2 = ""; // Your JSON string for Result2
    List<Result2> result2List = await dataService.GetMethod<Result2, JsonResult2>("someId", jsonString2);
}


I don't see how this is any improvement. From what I understand, the OP doesn't want to make X many MapFromJson methods, they want to make one MapFromJson that is generic.

Thank you for the code you wrote and the time you spent... but the problem was not solved... " new Result2Mapper();" This in itself is a problem

@gunr2171 Thanks for review , Yeah I got that, I am going to fix it

@YaYA I updated the code now , will this solve your problem?

@Behtash ty, Let Me Try
